# Does Waydroid run in a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I haven't found information regarding VM-support in [Waydroid](https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/pull/242), but there's at least a related [Github pull request](https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/pull/242). I don't currently run Ubuntu or any of its derivatives on my main machine.

I have [installed Waydroid](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops#ubuntu-debian-based-install-instructions) on Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) and  20.04 (Focal Fossa) in Oracle Virtualbox, but Android apps don't launch and no error messages are printed to the terminal.

Comment: Please file a bug report with the Waydroid developers.